# In a BST, how to make the left pointer point to the parent and the right point to the right sibling

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree

The right pointer can be made to point to the right sibling by performing a level order traversal and changing accordingly. However, i don't know the procedure to do this simultaneously. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1) Pictures are your friend 2) Where do you need something like that?

Answer (score 0):

In tournament problem you can use a gray-code to decide when its a left or right node. Another method is also if the value is less or equal then the parent value then its a right node.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a BFS and remember the level and parent. The following a c++ code for that

```
void BSTRightSibling(BSTNode *root)
{
    queue<BSTNode*> q;
    map<BSTNode*, BSTNode*> m;
    BSTNode* levelNode = root;

    q.push(root);
    while(! q.empty()) {
        BSTNode* n = q.front();
        if (n->left) {
            q.push(n->left);
            m[n->left] = n;
            if (n == levelNode) {
                levelNode = n->left;
            }
        }
        if (n->right) {
            q.push(n.right);
            m[n->right] = n;
            if (n == levelNode) {
                levelNode = n->right;
            }
        }
        q.pop();
        if ((!q.empty()) && (n != levelNode)) {
            n->right = q.front();
        } else {
            n->right = NULL;
        }
        n->left = m[n];
    }
}
```